# How to find all the running and ready task from Task Scheduler using taskschd.dll library

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

```
ITaskService s = new TaskSchedulerClass();

s.Connect(
    this.ControllerName, 
    Configuration.UserName, 
    Configuration.Domain, 
    Configuration.Password);

ITaskFolder tf = s.GetFolder("\\");

IRegisteredTaskCollection allTask = null;

IRunningTaskCollection allTaskRunning  = s.GetRunningTasks(0);
```

I am able to get the running task using `IRunningTaskCollection`, however cannot find ready tasks.

Comment: Check this link out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446865(v=vs.85).aspx  It might help.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a convenient method unfortunately, but you could write your own. Use recursion to traverse the task folder hierarchy. Something like this...

```
private static List<IRegisteredTask> GetReadyAndRunningTasks(
    ITaskFolder folder, 
    List<IRegisteredTask> readyAndRunningTasks = null)
{
    if (readyAndRunningTasks == null)
    {
        readyAndRunningTasks = new List<IRegisteredTask>();
    }

    IRegisteredTaskCollection tasks = folder.GetTasks(flags: 0);

    foreach (IRegisteredTask task in tasks)
    {
        if (task.State == _TASK_STATE.TASK_STATE_READY
            || task.State == _TASK_STATE.TASK_STATE_RUNNING)
        {
            readyAndRunningTasks.Add(task);
        }
    }

    foreach (ITaskFolder subFolder in folder.GetFolders(flags: 0))
    {
        GetReadyAndRunningTasks(subFolder, readyAndRunningTasks);
    }

    return readyAndRunningTasks;
}
```

And then call it like this...

```
List<IRegisteredTask> readyAndRunningTasks 
    = GetReadyAndRunningTasks(s.GetFolder(Path: "\\"));
```